# Casperjs catch console.log and console.error

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'am trying to catch site console.log and console.error by casperjs. In the case of console.log I have working code:

```
casper.on('remote.message', function(message) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + message);
});
```

But I can't figure out how to catch console.error. I need this for catching any resources error (like images not found).

Answer (score 10):

There's also the [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) handler:

```
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
     this.echo("Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});
```

Depending on which errors you need to catch, this one may be better.

Answer (score 3):

Ok it's weird to answer my own question but I found a solution on a coderwall blog posted by dpashkevich:

```
casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {
    var status = resource.status;
    if(status >= 400) {
        casper.log('Resource ' + resource.url + ' failed to load (' + status + ')', 'error');

        resourceErrors.push({
            url: resource.url,
            status: resource.status
        });
    }
});
```

Works brilliant

Comment: sorry but you're not answering the question, this doesn't catch console messages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following event to get remote errors:

```
casper.on("resource.error", function(resourceError) {
    this.echo("Resource error: " + "Error code: "+resourceError.errorCode+" ErrorString: "+resourceError.errorString+" url: "+resourceError.url+" id: "+resourceError.id, "ERROR");
});
```

Works like charm!